# Rails ActiveRecord, INSERT default field value in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This should be an easy one, but I've googled a fair bit.

I am trying to create a database log for my rails app. The log is a postgres table which has a `timestamp` field, which I have given a `DEFAULT` of `current_timestamp`. This works perfectly in raw SQL, if I leave the `timestamp` field out of my `INSERT` query, it gets the current timestamp correctly.

In rails I have;

```
entry = LogTable.new :fieldA => 'valA', :fieldB => 'valB'
entry.save
```

*(LogTable extends ActiveRecord::Base)*

Which results in an `INSERT` query that contains *all* fields, including the `timestamp` field set to `NULL`, which is not allowed by the database so it errors.

I have tried setting `:timestamp => 'current_timestamp'` and `:timestamp => 'DEFAULT'` but all end up trying to set it to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your current_timestamp just the current date/time? If so, you can stay simple and do something like:

```
entry = LogTable.new :fieldA => 'valA', :fieldB => 'valB', :timestamp => Time.now
```

If it's something more complex and you really want to use DB-side defaults, this page might help: http://drawohara.com/post/6677354/rails-activerecord-default-values.

Comment: I assumed that this would not work, as the field is actually a postgres `DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE` field, not just a simple unix timestamp. I am unable to check until tomorrow morning, but thanks for the input.

Comment: should work, as it's essentially the same as I deduce from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170. you may need to do `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now`, though I doubt (will be converted to UTC anyway, if I understand it right). still you may need to experiment.